# Notions and terms for extrema in preorders

Tags: definition, order-theory

I'm working on [a computer program for making decisions](https://github.com/Kodiologist/Artiruno) that represents the user's preferences as a preorder, as is common in theories of preference. I'd like to formalize the notions of "the best item", or "the *n* best items", ideally in a way that's consistent with past usage in order theory, but I'm having trouble finding discussion of extrema or extreme elements in preorders.

How I'd define an extremum in a preordered set $S$ is, an element $x ∈ S$ is a maximum of $S$ if $a ≤ x$ for all $a ∈ S$. Notice that this requires $x$ to be comparable to all other elements, although the preorder might not be total, and that $S$ can have more than one maximum (because in a preorder, there can be elements $x$, $y$ with $x ≤ y$ and $y ≤ x$ and yet $x ≠ y$).

I'd define the top-$n$ subset of $S$ to be the set of all elements $x ∈ S$ such that

- $x$ is comparable to all elements of $S$, and
- there are at most $n - 1$ distinct elements $a$ such that $a > x$.

For example, the top-3 subset of the negative integers with their usual order is $\{-3, -2, -1\}$. Notice that the set of all of $S$'s maxima coincides with its top-1 subset. Also, the top-$n$ subset need not have exactly $n$ elements; it can have any cardinality from 0 to $|S|$.

Can you point me to any previously established terms for these notions, or to notions similar to these?

Comment: Reasonable question, though I haven't heard of such notions, and it seems they're at least obscure. It would probably help if you had a specific use case in mind. What properties of an extrema notion are desirable? Your top-$n$ is a bit funny in that it doesn't have $n$ elements, as you note. Maybe restricting to total preorders is fine for you.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson I regard the subjects' preferences as total, in theory; I use a non-total representation only to represent my incomplete knowledge of their preferences. I think this is the most obvious way to formalize "the best *n* items", but maybe you have a better idea. My use case is very specific, so I'm not sure what to add about that.

Comment: Well, totally heuristically, I'm suspicious of "chaotic" or "discontinuous" statistics. Your top-n statistic becomes empty if you just add a single disconnected item. I'd tend to count incomparable elements as implicitly greater than the current element for purposes of deciding if the current element is a top-n or not. But again, I'm just wildly guessing at what specific properties you want in a real use case.